# How can I convert the input operator (+,-) to math in C

Tags: operator-keyword, converters

Assume that the given input are 5,+,5 in C.
ex)
5
+
5

And I would like to get the answer 10.

I thought code like the below.

```
#include
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a,b,symbol;

    cin >> a >> symbol >> b;
    printf("%d", (a-'0') symbol (b-'0'));
    return 0;
}
```

Expected value is 10. However, I got an error in symbol
How would I get the solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things that I noticed:

First, you are printing integer, but `a` and `b` are both `char`s.

Knowing that there are only a few symbols that you can use, maybe a `switch` `case` would be more appropriate?

```c
int main(){
   int a, b;
   char symbol;
   switch(symbol){
       case('-'): print("%d", a - b);
       case('+'): print("%d", a + b);
       case('*'): print("%d", a * b);
       case('/'): print("%d", a / b);
       case('%'): print("%d", a % b);
       default :  print("Not a known symbol");
   }
```

Second: Why are you substracting a from the character 0?